# Laravel envoy error - Call to undefined method

Tags: laravel, laravel-envoy

When I run `envoy ssh` it works however if I try and run `envoy run list` which is just a ls command, it returns:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::fromShellCommandline()

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
I am using latest laravel 6.2 and latest laravel envoy

```
@servers(['localhost' => '127.0.0.1'])

@task('list')
    ls
@endtask
```

Comment: Did you try to update your dependencies like composer update and composer autodump

Comment: @DannyEbbers yep I have tried that

Comment: And do you have a task/story called `list` in your Envoy.blade.php? What does it look like?

Comment: @kerbholz yes i do

Comment: I reinstalled it and it works

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled envoy with the latest version and seems to have fixed the problem.